# Wix is not allowed the user to override the directory

Tags: wix

I am using customized UI which works in a flow of different views like installview, progressview, finishview, uninstallview etc. In the custom installer there is two options, One is to change the install directory and other to change the database directory. My custom installer contains two msi. whenever I tried to pass the database directory to the msi it will not overide. It always taking the default path.

my custom installer contains a variable for database which is overidable, and passing the value to the msi.

```
<Variable Name="DatabaseFolder" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value="[CommonAppDataFolder]$(var.ManufacturerName)\$(var.ProductName)" />


<MsiPackage Id="StorageApp"
              DisplayInternalUI="no"
              DisplayName="$(var.StorageApp)"
              Permanent="no"
              Visible="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="$(var.StorageAppExe)"
              Compressed="yes">  
              <MsiProperty Name="DATABASEAPPDATAFOLDER" Value="[DatabaseFolder]" />
  </MsiPackage>
```

By default it takes the DatabaseProductName as the directory name. But if i changed the directory it always taking the default path. Why i couldn't overide the default value. Is there anything missing in my code?

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="CompanyAppDataFolder" Name="$(var.DatabaseManufacturerName)">
      <Directory Id="DATABASEAPPDATAFOLDER" Name="$(var.DatabaseProductName)">
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "*But if I changed the directory...*". Did you change the value of **$(var.DatabaseProductName)** or just the **Directory Id**?

Make sure you verify your directory structure by setting a directory name directly in the "**Name=**" attribute instead of passing a  value through **$(var.DatabaseProductName)**

Example:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="CompanyAppDataFolder" Name="Folder1">
      <Directory Id="DATABASEAPPDATAFOLDER" Name="SubFolder1">
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Just a reminder. The **Directory Id** is just for you to reference your folder elsewhere in your .wxs file. The string that you fill in for the "**Name=**" attribute will be the actual name of your folder when you ultimately install your application.